# Why is MKMapView being retained after its parent controller has been popped off navigation stack?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I have found a few questions relating to this on SO and elsewhere, but none have a definitive answer.  As far as I can tell, using ARC, my MKMapView is not being released (or at least is leaving garbage on the heap) when the view controller that contains it is released.

I don't *think* this is a silly problem on my end - I have spent a lot of time pouring over my code, testing small bits at a time, taking countless heapshots, ensuring that the mapView's delegate is being set to nil, etc, and in the end, this simple line:

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 3, 154, 171)];
```

is allocating memory that builds up by ~200 KB every time I go in and out of the view controller in which mapView is located.

So, my question is this: can anyone explain what is going on here?  Is there a reason that ARC is not releasing memory taken up by my MKMapView?  Is this a known issue?  It looks an awful lot like a retain cycle to me, and quite a bit of memory is being lost, but it seems to me like this must be something going on behind the scenes...

**EDIT**

Here is the property declaration for my `mapView`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView;
```

Keep in mind that the one and only thing I am doing with this `MKMapView` is alloc and init, as seen in the line from my original question (of course I'd like to do more with this map view, but I have narrowed it down to this line being the only part that is causing the leak - `mapView` is never even inserted into a view).  When I comment that single line out, the leak disappears.

Comment: Did you try to set `self.mapView=nil;` on `viewDidUnload` of your VC?

Comment: You should not depend on `viewDidUnload`. Just for the test I would create a method like `-(void)release { self.mapView=nil; }` and call it at appropriate moment. If this releases the memory you'll know that the problem is in ARC not releasing it. You could also try `myView = nil;` after you stop using it.

Comment: Can you post your property declarations for your map view and delegate as well?

Comment: I tried setting `self.mapView` to `nil`, and it is as if doing so releases some memory, but not all of it - the same amount of memory that was leaking before is still leaking now, but most of the memory that was previously being released when I popped my VC off the nav controller stack is now being released immediately (because I am doing so at the end of `viewDidLoad`).  @lxt, please see the edit to my question above.